# Unable to access JSON property values

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-scope

This has been driving me crazy, and i know it must be something really simple i am missing!

I have a service that returns a JSON object:

```
[{"accountId":"0000004000006195","title":null,"firstName":"JOE","middleName":"BLOG","lastName":"BLOGGS","suffix":null,"primaryAddress":{"addressLine1":"TEST ADDRESS CLOSE","addressLine2":null,"addressLine3":"MY TOWN","town":"Washington","county":null,"country":"US","postcode":"PO9868"},"customerTelephones":[{"phoneNumber":"09876543455","type":"Alternate 1"},{"phoneNumber":"98654345676","type":"Alternate 2"}],"birthDate":108628400000}]
```

I am trying to display properties of the JSON, eg firstname using:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.testJson = [{"accountId":"0000004000006195","title":null,"firstName":"JOE","middleName":"BLOG","lastName":"BLOGGS","suffix":null,"primaryAddress":{"addressLine1":"TEST ADDRESS CLOSE","addressLine2":null,"addressLine3":"MY TOWN","town":"Washington","county":null,"country":"US","postcode":"PO9868"},"customerTelephones":[{"phoneNumber":"09876543455","type":"Alternate 1"},{"phoneNumber":"98654345676","type":"Alternate 2"}],"birthDate":108628400000}]
});
```

HTML:

```
<p>{{testJson}}</p>

<p>{{testJson.firstName}}</p>
```

But for some reason, {{testJson.firstName}} is showing as blank!

Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/VWJfcXTPaDut2jqB4W3o?p=preview

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$scope.testJson` is `Array` you need get element by index and then get property by `Object`

```
 {{testJson[0].firstName}}
```

[`Example`](http://plnkr.co/edit/zizOIaSEuLt1yuluHyE9?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

Your testJson seems to be an array. So `{{testJson[0].firstName}}` should do the trick!